# Need help setting up dev environment

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on different windows machines and virtual windows machines on a mac. I have a project wich uses SQL server and AD for autentication.

Right now I have to be connected to VPN so that the asp.net web application can connect to AD using LDAP string to autentivate users, I also have the SQL server on the other side of the VPN connection.

Is there any way to setup my enviroment so that I can work locally without the AD, and on a local SQL server and be able to publish the project without manually changing the web.config file?

Comment: From what you're saying, it sounds like you are developing against your production database - this is a BAD thing!

Comment: I'm developing against a "pre prod" database, so it's only for testing, but the AD is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make some publish profiles, they affect your web.config automatically when you select the profile.

Seen [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065492/different-connection-string-for-each-publish-profile-in-vs2010)
Hope I can help you a bit !